# NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.findFormatOverrides on Databricks

Tags: scala, maven, jackson, azure-databricks, azure-security

I'm working on a rather big project. I need to use azure-security-keyvault-secrets, so I added following to my pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run this sample code:

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // get vault name from system env -> databricks
    val secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
      .vaultUrl("https://myVault.vault.azure.net/")
      .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
      .buildClient

    val secret = secretClient.getSecret("AzureAccountName")
    println("===================== " + secret.getValue)
  }

}
```

I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.createContextual(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.createContextual(InstantDeserializer.java:241)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:669)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:430)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:947)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:439)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:296)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:428)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:947)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:439)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:296)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:461)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3838)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3732)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2764)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.deserialize(JacksonAdapter.java:174)
```

After some intensive use of Google, it always came back to the same cause. There must be some inconsistency between my dependency versions. So probably some other dependency imports an other version of Jackson. But when I print the tree I don't see any mismatch:

```
- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.10.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
\- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
```

Full tree:

```
     +- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:jar:3.0.1:compile
 |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile
 |  +- org.scalactic:scalactic_2.11:jar:3.0.1:compile
 |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.8:compile
 |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.5:compile
 |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
 +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
 +- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
 +- org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_2.11:jar:2.4.3:provided
 |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.9.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:4.0.2:compile
 |  |  |     \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
 |  |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.9.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.0.4:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.6.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-kvstore_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.6.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
 |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
 |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
 |  |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.0:compile
 |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.3.2-2:compile
 |  |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.7.45:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.roaringbitmap:shims:jar:0.7.45:compile
 |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
 |  |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.11:jar:3.5.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.2:compile
 |  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
 |  |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
 |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.5:compile
 |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.5:compile
 |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.5:compile
 |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
 |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
 |  |  +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.13:compile
 |  |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.7:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-mllib-local_2.11:jar:2.4.3:provided
 |  |  \- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:jar:0.13.2:provided
 |  |     +- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:jar:0.13.2:provided
 |  |     +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:provided
 |  |     +- com.github.rwl:jtransforms:jar:2.4.0:provided
 |  |     \- org.spire-math:spire_2.11:jar:0.13.0:provided
 |  |        +- org.spire-math:spire-macros_2.11:jar:0.13.0:provided
 |  |        \- org.typelevel:machinist_2.11:jar:0.6.1:provided
 |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm6-shaded:jar:4.8:compile
 |  +- com.github.fommil.netlib:core:jar:1.1.2:provided
 |  +- net.sourceforge.f2j:arpack_combined_all:jar:0.1:provided
 |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.5:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
 +- be.bluecrux:bluecrux-lop-commons:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.7.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:jar:2.4.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.9:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.9:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:nohive:1.5.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.5.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 |  |  |  \- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.10:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:jar:nohive:1.5.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.10.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.10.1:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.10.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.10.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:jar:2.4.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.10.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:0.10.0:compile
 |  |     +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:0.10.0:compile
 |  |     +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory:jar:0.10.0:compile
 |  |     +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.2:compile
 |  |     \- com.vlkan:flatbuffers:jar:1.2.0-3f79e055:compile
 |  +- au.com.bytecode:opencsv:jar:2.4:compile
 |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.6:compile
 |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |  +- com.github.scopt:scopt_2.11:jar:3.2.0:compile
 |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:jar:8.6.0:compile
 |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:jar:2.9.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.9.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-sslengine:jar:6.1.26:compile
 |  |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
 |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
 |  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.9.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
 |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
 |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
 |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core4:jar:4.1.0-incubating:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
 |  +- com.github.tototoshi:scala-csv_2.11:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  \- org.mockito:mockito-inline:jar:2.27.0:compile
 |     \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.27.0:compile
 |        +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.10:compile
 |        +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.10:compile
 |        \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:compile
 +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.9.0:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
 |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.0:compile
 |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.0:runtime
 +- com.chuusai:shapeless_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
 |  \- org.typelevel:macro-compat_2.11:jar:1.1.1:compile
 +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.2.1.jre8:compile
 +- neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:jar:2.4.0-M6:compile
 |  +- org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:jar:1.7.2:compile
 |  \- graphframes:graphframes:jar:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11:compile
 +- org.opencypher:spark-cypher:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  +- org.opencypher:okapi-relational:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.opencypher:okapi-logical:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |     \- org.opencypher:okapi-ir:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |        \- org.atnos:eff_2.11:jar:5.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.opencypher:okapi-neo4j-io:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.opencypher:okapi-api:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |     +- org.typelevel:cats-core_2.11:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |     |  +- org.typelevel:cats-macros_2.11:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |     |  \- org.typelevel:cats-kernel_2.11:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |     +- org.opencypher:front-end-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  +- org.opencypher:util-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  +- org.opencypher:expressions-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  +- org.opencypher:rewriting-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  |  \- org.opencypher:ast-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  +- org.opencypher:parser-9.0:jar:9.0.20181030:compile
 |  |     |  \- org.scalacheck:scalacheck_2.11:jar:1.12.5:compile
 |  |     |     \- org.scala-sbt:test-interface:jar:1.0:compile
 |  |     \- com.lihaoyi:upickle_2.11:jar:0.6.6:compile
 |  |        \- com.lihaoyi:ujson_2.11:jar:0.6.6:compile
 |  +- org.opencypher:graph-ddl:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.opencypher:okapi-trees:jar:0.2.1:compile
 |  |  \- com.lihaoyi:fastparse_2.11:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  |     +- com.lihaoyi:fastparse-utils_2.11:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  |     \- com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.11:jar:0.1.4:compile
 |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.12:compile
 |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-scala_2.11:jar:11.0:compile
 +- org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.5:test
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.5:test
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:5.5.5:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-fulltext-index:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-data-collector:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-parser-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ast-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-expressions-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-rewriting-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:3.1.9:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-codegen:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:6.2:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:6.2:test
 |  |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:6.2:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.12:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3:jar:2.3.12:test
 |  |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4.2:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.9:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1:jar:3.1.9:test
 |  |  |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.3.3:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-planner-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:openCypher-frontend-1:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-util-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-expression-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-ir-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-logical-plans-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-planner-spi-3.4:jar:3.4.13:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-legacy:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-util-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-planner-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-ir-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-front-end-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-logical-plans-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-planner-spi-3.5:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-runtime-util:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-interpreted-runtime:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-bolt:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j:pom:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-security:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-dbms:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-import-tool:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  +- org.jprocesses:jProcesses:jar:1.6.4:test
 |  |  |  |  \- com.profesorfalken:WMI4Java:jar:1.6.1:test
 |  |  |  |     \- com.profesorfalken:jPowerShell:jar:1.9:test
 |  |  |  +- org.neo4j.licensing-proxy:zstd-proxy:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-command-line:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.4:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:server-api:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.neo4j.3rdparty.javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.2.r612:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j.client:neo4j-browser:jar:3.2.20:test
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.17.v20190418:test
 |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19.3:test
 |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19.3:test
 |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
 |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:test
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
 |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:test
 |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:test
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.0.1:test
 |  |  |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.7.8:test
 |  |  |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.13:test
 |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:test
 |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.0.1:test
 |  |  |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.5:test
 |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:test
 |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:test-jar:tests:3.5.6:test
 |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:test-jar:tests:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-annotation-processors:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-procedure-api:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel-api:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-diagnostics:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-values:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.5:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-configuration:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-index:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial-index:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-ssl:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  \- org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections:jar:9.2.0:test
 |  |     \- org.eclipse.collections:eclipse-collections-api:jar:9.2.0:test
 |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:test-jar:tests:3.5.6:test
 |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-concurrent:jar:3.5.6:test
 |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.3:test
 |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.3:test
 |  +- org.neo4j.app:neo4j-server:test-jar:tests:3.5.6:test
 |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
 |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.5.6:test
 +- com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:jar:4.0.1:compile
 |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.1.0:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  |  |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
 |  |  |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.26.Final:compile
 |  \- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.1.0:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.42.Final:compile
 |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.0.RELEASE:compile
 |        \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-pool:jar:0.1.0.RELEASE:compile
 +- com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:0.5.0-preview:compile
 |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.6:compile
 |  +- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:6.14:compile
 |  |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
 |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile (version selected from constraint [1.3.1,2.3])
 |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4.4:compile (version selected from constraint [1.4.3,))
 |  |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:8.4:compile (version selected from constraint [6.0.1,))
 |  +- org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:5.4.0:compile
 |     \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.4.0:compile
 +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
 |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.10.0:compile
 +- org.testcontainers:mssqlserver:jar:1.12.3:test
 |  \- org.testcontainers:jdbc:jar:1.12.3:test
 |     \- org.testcontainers:database-commons:jar:1.12.3:test
 |        \- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar:1.12.3:test
 |           +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
 |           |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
 |           +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:17.0.0:test
 |           +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:test
 |           +- org.rnorth.duct-tape:duct-tape:jar:1.0.8:test
 |           +- org.rnorth.visible-assertions:visible-assertions:jar:2.1.2:test
 |           \- org.rnorth:tcp-unix-socket-proxy:jar:1.0.2:test
 |              +- com.kohlschutter.junixsocket:junixsocket-native-common:jar:2.0.4:test
 |              |  \- org.scijava:native-lib-loader:jar:2.0.2:test
 |              \- com.kohlschutter.junixsocket:junixsocket-common:jar:2.0.4:test
 \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.1:test
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here ?

**EDIT**
I'm using Databricks Runtime 6.2. This runtime version uses jackson version 2.6.7 and azure-security-keyvault-secrets uses version 2.10.0. 
[image]
I think this is conflicting and causes the error to occur. Is there maybe a possibility to ignore the jackson version in Databricks?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-java?

Comment: Yes I did, why?

Comment: findFormatOverrides is since 2.7. I'd suggest just overriding jackson version in your pom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to fix the problem with the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). I added following piece of code to my pom.xml file:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>com.company-name.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.company-name.Test</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded-jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

With this shaded-fat-jar I am able to use an higher version of jackson, which causes my code to run fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use older version of JSR310
Below dependency worked for me

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```